# Check if given month+date is present in the data containing range of month+date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2000

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @MM INT -- Current month
DECLARE @DD INT -- Current date

SET @MM = 1 -- For testing, set it to January
SET @DD = 1 -- For testing, set it to 01

SELECT xxxID, xxxFK, StartMonth, StartDate, StopMonth, StopDate, NULL AS OKorNOT
FROM xxxTable
ORDER BY xxxFK
```

And here is the data:

```
xxxID            xxxFK       StartMonth  StartDate   StopMonth   StopDate    OKorNOT     
---------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- 
8                2287        11          15          1           2           NULL
4                2290        2           1           2           21          NULL
2                2306        9           15          10          31          NULL
3                2306        1           3           1           20          NULL
9                2661        11          15          1           3           NULL
10               2661        5           5           5           31          NULL
5                3778        6           2           9           5           NULL
6                3778        1           1           3           31          NULL
7                3778        5           10          5           31          NULL
1                3778        12          10          12          31          NULL
```

I need to populate OKorNot column with 1/0 depending on whether the given month-date lies between StartMonth-StartDate and StopMonth-StopDate. This is SQL Server 2000 by the way.

## EDIT

The thing here to note that is that there are no years stored in the data and the months-dates may start in, say Nov-15 and end in Jan-15 so on Dec-31 and Jan-1 this case should return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using integer operations only and an imaginary 384-days calendar**

Since your dates are combinations of month and day, I tried to create an integer for every such combination, an integer that is unique and also preserves order. To have calculations as simple as possible, we invent a new calendar where all months have exactly 32 days and we act as if our dates are from this calendar. Then to get how many days have past since 1st of January, we have the formula:

`DaysPast = 32 * month + day`

*(OK, it should be `32 * (month-1) + (day-1)` but this way it's simpler and we only want to compare dates relatively to one another, not to January 1st. And the result is still unique for every date).*

Therefore, we first calculate the `DaysPast` for our check date:

`SET @CHECK = 32 * @MM + @DD`

Then, we calculate the `DaysPast` for all dates (both start and stop ones) in our table:

```
  ( SELECT *
         , (32 * StartMonth + StartDate) AS Start
         , (32 * StopMonth  + StopDate ) AS Stop
    FROM xxxTable
  ) AS temp
```

Then, we have two cases.

- First case, when `Start = (8-Feb)` and `Stop = (23-Nov)`.

Then, the first condition `@CHECK BETWEEN Start AND Stop` will be true and the dates between Start and Stop will be OK.

The second condition will be False, so no more dates will be OK.

- Second case, when `Start = (23-Nov)` and `Stop = (8-Feb)`.  :

Then, the first condition `@CHECK BETWEEN Start AND Stop` will be false because Start is bigger than Stop so no dates can match this condition.

The second condition `Stop < Start` will be true, so we also test if
`@CHECK` is NOT `BETWEEN (9-Feb) AND (22-Nov)`
to match the dates that are before `(9-Feb)` or after `(22-Nov)`.

```
DECLARE @CHECK INT
SET @CHECK = 32 * @MM + @DD

SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN
           @CHECK BETWEEN Start AND Stop 
           OR ( Stop < Start 
               AND @CHECK NOT BETWEEN Stop+1 AND Start-1
              )
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END
       AS OKorNOT
FROM 
  ( SELECT *
         , (32 * StartMonth + StartDate) AS Start
         , (32 * StopMonth  + StopDate ) AS Stop
    FROM xxxTable
  ) AS temp
ORDER BY xxxFK
```

Comment: This one looks easier to understand but I'd appreciate if you could one/two lines of explanation how handles the wrap around case.

Comment: Excellent, I was confused about the second case which you just explained. I am back to work so I can now test the query. I'll check for border line cases but this looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you'd stored dates as, well, dates...

Anyway, something like this. I haven't tested. And you need to deal with year boundary which I've done

```
SELECT
    xxxID, xxxFK, StartMonth, StartDate, StopMonth, StopDate,
    CASE 
       WHEN
          FullStart <= FullStop AND 
            DATEADD(month, @MM-1, DATEADD(day, @DD-1, 0)) BETWEEN FullStart AND FullStop
                      THEN 1
       WHEN
          FullStart > FullStop AND 
            DATEADD(month, @MM-1, DATEADD(day, @DD-1, 0)) BETWEEN
                    FullStart AND DATEADD(year, 1, FullStop)
                      THEN 1  
       ELSE 0
    END AS OKOrNot
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        xxxID, xxxFK, StartMonth, StartDate, StopMonth, StopDate,
        DATEADD(month, StartMonth-1, DATEADD(day, StartDate-1, 0)) AS FullStart,
        DATEADD(month, StopMonth-1, DATEADD(day, StopDate-1, 0)) AS FullStop
    FROM xxxTable
    ) foo
ORDER BY xxxFK
```

edit: added "-1" to all values: if we're already Jan don't add another month...

Comment: I checked, it failed for case #1 `(8, 2287, 11, 15, 1, 2, 0)` with date `Jan/1`... should have returned 1/true/OK.

Comment: @Salman A: have you tried playing with this? I don't have SQL Server in front of me

Comment: Change the `FullStop` column definition like this: `DATEADD(year, CASE StopMonth * 100 + StopDay < StartMonth * 100 + StartDay THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, DATEADD(month, StopMonth-1, DATEADD(day, StopDate-1, 0))) AS FullStop`, i.e. the current expression should be nested into the added `DATEADD(year, ...)`.

Comment: @gbn: When `FullStart > FullStop` one more condition is needed. As it is, only dates at the end of the year, after `FullStart` will be OK. Dates at the start of the year, before `FullStop` need to be checked too.

Comment: @ypercube, @Andriy M: I thought I'd covered that with ´WHEN FullStart > FullStop´ ... ´DATEADD(year, 1, FullStop)´

Comment: @gbn: Seems like you have, sorry.

Comment: @gbn , @Andriy: It doesn't seem to me. If FullStart is in Nov, and FullStop in Feb, then you only check if the @MM@DD date is **after** FullStart. So, January dates will be omitted.

Comment: @ypercube: ah yes, I see now. I'll +1 your answer instead of fixing this

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM xxxTable
WHERE (StartMonth < StopMonth OR StartMonth = StopMonth AND StartDate<=StopDate)
    AND (@MM > StartMonth OR @MM = StartMonth AND @DD >= StartDate)
    AND (@MM < StopMonth OR @MM = StopMonth AND @DD <= StopDate)
    OR (StartMonth > StopMonth OR StartMonth = StopMonth AND StartDate>StopDate)
        AND ((@MM > StartMonth OR @MM = StartMonth AND @DD >= StartDate)
            OR (@MM < StopMonth OR @MM = StopMonth AND @DD <= StopDate))
```